# Си: неодинаковое отношение к расширениям

Tags: c, winapi

День добрый! Обнаружил такую фигню. Вот программа на Си:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>

int main ()
{
WinExec("C:\\exe\\sbatibez\\cherezbat.bat", SW_SHOWNORMAL);    
WinExec( "C:\\exe\\sbatibez\\bezbat.js", SW_SHOWNORMAL);    
return 0;
}
```

Содержание cherezbat.bat:

```
cd /d %0\..
start cherezbat.js
```

Содержание cherezbat.js:

```
WshShell = 
WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
WScript.Echo("Этот сценарий запущен через батник");
```

Содержание bezbat.js:

```
WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell");
WScript.Echo("Этот сценарий запущен без участия батника");
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему при запуске моей прогры окно с сообщением "Этот сценарий запущен через батник" вылезает, а окно с другим сообщением - нет?

Comment: может нужно добавить start?

Comment: Вызывайте `WinExec("wscript bezbat.js", SW_SHOWNORMAL);` Или, если хотите в консоли - `WinExec("cscript bezbat.js", SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Answer (score 1):

Ну не понимает Windows, что такое js, в функции `WinExec`.

Кстати, почему бы вас не смотреть, что именно возвращает функция? Ведь половина вопросов пропала бы :)

Вот такой код (кстати, почему вы выбрали тег `c`, если используете `iostream`?)

```
string ErrMsg(UINT e = 0)
{
    char buf[1024];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,NULL,
                  e ? e : GetLastError(),NULL,
                  buf,1024,NULL);
    return buf;
}

int main ()
{
    UINT e = WinExec("cherezbat.js", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    cout << ErrMsg(e) << endl;

}
```

выведет сообщение

> Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

Вот и ответ. Для `js` есть два "исполнителя", в зависимости от варианта работы - оконный и консольный, `wscript` и `cscript`, и в вызове лучше использовать их, например

```
WinExec("wscript cherezbat.js", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Но - вы вообще уверены в том, что вам нужен код, запускающий что-то через `WinExec`? может, написать всю программу на js или вообще на языке командного интерпретатора? (ныне незаслуженно забытое искусство :))

Comment: > iostream я и слова-то такого не знаю. Откуда оно взялось? Все составлено из частей кодов блогов, справок по Си. Насчет программы на js, cmd. Даже если считать, что  я могу батник закрепить на панели задач, я не смогу закрепить в нее файлы, насколько я знаю. По этой же причине отпадает программа на js.

Comment: > Кстати, почему бы вас не смотреть, что именно возвращает функция? Ведь половина вопросов пропала бы :) - я еще не умел, да, думаю, и не умею это делать.

Comment: А реакция на код из вашего ответ вообще следующая: https://i.postimg.cc/mZ30Kstf/image.png

Comment: @mathem `#include <iostream>` - это штуковина из С++, не С. Насчет ошибки - надо нужные `#include ...` добавить.

Comment: Ну, если все сводится к тому, что нужно ярлык на панель положить, то спрашивать нужно именно об этом, а не о том,  какой рукой надо держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей. Что до компиляции - включайте все нужные заголовки, компи... знаете, возитесь сами. Я разжевал, в рот положил, ну надо же и вам потрудиться. Все компилируется и нормально работает. Естественно, я привел важный фрагмент кода без заголовочных файлов; если вы так и компилируете - без них - то кто же вам доктор?... Словом, я умываю руки, тем более что началась очередная нормальная рабочая неделя, есть куча других дел...